# Entity Framework One to many fluent Api - foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping, ef-fluent-api

I would like to make connection between two entitites.

I have Entity_1 and Entity_2  with relationship one - to many (one Entity_1 can have multiple Entity_2).

So I have my entities:
Entity

```
    class Entity_1
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Entity_2Id{ get; set; }
        public virtual Entity_2 Entity_2{ get; set; } 
    }

    class Entity_2
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Entity_2Id{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Entity_1> Entity_1s{ get; set; }
    }
```

How Can I make connection that I have foreign key (Entity_1) in Entity 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one Entity_1 can have multiple Entity_2

This means, that `Entity_1` (optionally) has a collection of `Entity_2`, and `Entity_2` (optionally) has a reference to `Entity_1`:

```
class Entity_1
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Entity_2> Entity_2s{ get; set; }
}

class Entity_2
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Entity_1Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity_1 Entity_1 { get; set; }
}
```

while your entities are incorrect.
Fluent API for the code above is:

```
HasRequired(_ => _.Entity_1)
    .WithMany(_ => _.Entity_2s)
    .HasForeignKey(_ => _.Entity_1Id);
```

More options available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620).